# Expectation of the Estimated Slope

Tags: expected-value, linear-regression

In the following [book](http://stat88.org/textbook/notebooks/Chapter_12/02_The_Distribution_of_the_Estimated_Slope.html), the expectation of the estimated slope with linear regression is derived as follows:

$$
\begin{align*}
\hat{\beta}_1 ~ &= ~ \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \\
E(\hat{\beta_1}) ~ &= ~ \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})\boldsymbol{E(Y_i - \bar{Y})}}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \\
\dots
\end{align*} 
$$

The end of the derivation is non-important and obvious, but I don't understand why the following part is treated as a constant?

$$
~ \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}
$$

which results in expectation operator only being applied to $Y_i - \bar{Y}$. $x_i$ is a random variable too right?

Comment: $x_i$ is a constant.

Comment: I think the idea here is that the points $x_i$ are the known points where we measure $Y,$ so they're just constants.

Comment: @StephenDonovan yeah I suppose it makes sense, when we want to know the relationship for instance between age and resting heart rate, age is a fixed range. Although, if you took a sample of people and you measured their HR and #hours a person ran every week, both would be random variables... So basically, this derivation is under the assumption that $x_i$ is constant?